# native Fabric 8 on openshift

Tags: fabric8

I get the following on a native openshift fabric8 installation. this then results in not been able to access the fabric8 console. Thank you in advance! 
[error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZLbQ.png)

Comment: Screenshots are discouraged because they aren't searchable and tend to rot. Please copy and paste the error message into the post directly. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/733092

Comment: You should probably post to fabric8.io community or ping someone on IRC there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the output of these commands:

> oc get route
>
> oc get pods
>
> oc describe rc fabric8

That might give us a clue as to what is going on.

Did you supply a domain parameter to gofabric8?

Full [instructions are here](http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/openshift.html) along with a 
[troubleshooting guide](http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/troubleshooting.html).